# How would I access this JSON data in AngularJS?

Tags: json, angularjs

I am trying to learn how to load JSON with Angular. I'm a beginner with both topics, and am stuck on some really beginner topics.

I have a JSON file called food.json. It has structure like this:

```
 [
  {"uid":"55","title":"Nussbrot","code":"U VP 0000030","unit":[{"title":""}],"unitgram":"0","unitgram_second":"0","sorting":"0"},
  {"uid":"58","title":"Walnu\u00dfbrot","code":"X 39 2000002","unit":[{"title":"Scheiben"}],"unitgram":"45","unitgram_second":"0","sorting":"0"}
 ]
```

Following instructions from http://toddmotto.com/ultimate-guide-to-learning-angular-js-in-one-day/, I have a controller like this:

```
myApp.controller('EmailsCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

$scope.foodlist = {};
$scope.foodlist.foodtitle = '';

$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'food.json'
})
.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
  $scope.foodlist = data.; //I don't know what to call here as my data elements have no names?
})
.error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
  //error
});
}]);
```

The first point I am stuck in is, how do I assign data to my ´$scope.foodlist´ if the JSON objects have no names?

[I've built a Plunkr of my not-working attempts so far](http://plnkr.co/edit/V1ct7J5OiSzuL3zJUGZq?p=preview), and would appreciate any guidance in a) reading in the JSON and b) assigning the JSON data to values in controller.

Comment: You should familiarise yourself with stepping through in chrome - this allows you to put a break point at the $scope.foodlist = ... command and then put a watch on the returned variable - you will then see that data is likely to be an array, which is all you need to assign (I think). So you need to iterate through your array to return individual objects as you appear to be trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-repeat` in your case will iterate the array of objects in your data

You just need to use :

```
<li ng-repeat="food in foodlist">
```

Then on each pass of the loop,  angular will reference the current object in array to produce output like `{{ food.title }}`

I updated your [**demo here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/I1XNd4WgP5gzk5AczBtm?p=preview)

**Edit** Strongly suggest you go through the tutorial on angular docs site step by step

Comment: Thanks for the updated Plunkr, it shows clearly where I was going wrong. You're right, the AngularJS docs are a much better source than the tutorial I was trying to follow.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is in the controller definition: You are trying to reference $http but you are not passing it in.

`myApp.controller('EmailsCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {`

Then on `success` your `data` parameter is your `foodlist`:

`.success(function (data, status, headers, config) { $scope.foodlist = data; })`

Finally, in your html, `ng-repeat` should be like this:

`ng-repeat="food in foodlist"`