# Wordpress filter custom post type with json api

Tags: json, wordpress

I want to query for custom post type with json api and get back following response for custom post type.

Is it possible to parse this response and display?

```
"a:4:{i:0;a:1:{s:11:"instruction";s:149:"Patlıcanları alacalı soyup iri doğrayın. Yağlı kağıt serili fırın tepsisine alın. Üzerlerine zeytinyağı gezdirip tuz karabiber serpin.";}i:1;a:1:{s:11:"instruction";s:193:"Önceden ısıtılmış 200 derece fırında 30-35 dakika kadar közleyin. Kalan zeytinyağını ayrı bir tavada ısıtın. İnce doğradığınız yeşillikleri hafif soteleyip ocaktan alın.";}i:2;a:1:{s:11:"instruction";s:185:"Közlediğiniz patlıcanlar, yeşillikler, rendelediğiniz beyaz peynir, yoğurt ve sebze suyunu geniş bir kaseye alın. Pürüzsüz bir kıvam elde edinceye kadar blenderdan geçirin.";}i:3;a:1:{s:11:"instruction";s:109:"Buzdolabına iki saat dinlendirin. Üzerini halka fesleğen yaprakları ile süsleyerek soğuk servis yapın";}}"
```

Like instruction  step 1 Step 2.

Comment: Please format your `JSON string` . It is hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

**For PHP**

`json_decode()` Takes a JSON encoded string and converts it into a PHP variable.

For more info:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

You can find implementation code here:

[Parsing JSON file with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343596/parsing-json-file-with-php)
[How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)

**For JavaScript**

[How to access JSON encoded data of an array using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21040794/how-to-access-json-encoded-data-of-an-array-using-javascript)

**For Angular JS**

[How would I access this JSON data in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19689511/how-would-i-access-this-json-data-in-angularjs)
[How to access JSON array object in HTML using angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28175381/how-to-access-json-array-object-in-html-using-angular)

Comment: Thank you for the the answer. Is it possible to make the same implementation for Angular and JavaScript?

Comment: Check info added to answer

Comment: Could you please provide a sample code if possible for Angular? The json object in the example is not complicated as json object I provided